# How do I shrink my text field and position labels in the bottom right using BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I am told to use `BorderLayout` for this project. I am unsure how to properly size my text field and I am not sure how to put the `JLabel` `answerCelsius` into the bottom right corner.

I attempted to change the textfield with the code - `farenheit.setPreferredSize((new Dimension(80,20)));`
This doesn't seem to do anything.

Does using `BorderLayout` allow you to align to the `SouthEast` Grid? Or is there only 5 separate grids?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class JTemperature implements ActionListener {

    /** initialize the frame, labels, and textfield so I can use them in 
later methods
 */
private JTextField farenheit;
private JLabel name, enter, degreesFarenheit, answer, answerCelsius;
private JFrame jfrm;

JTemperature() {

    /** Makes a Jframe and titles it Temperature Converter
     */
    jfrm = new JFrame("Temperature Converter");

    /**
      set my borders and layout
     */
    jfrm.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    /** sets size of Jframe
     */
    jfrm.setSize(240, 120);

    /** when the jframe closes it exits by default
     */
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(jfrm.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /** initialize the label name
     */
    name = new JLabel("(c) First name, Last", JLabel.CENTER);


    /** initialize the label enter
     */
    enter = new JLabel("Enter: ", JLabel.CENTER);

    /** initialize the label answerCelsius
     */
    answerCelsius = new JLabel("degrees C", JLabel.CENTER);

    /** initialize the label degreesFarenheit
     */
    degreesFarenheit = new JLabel("degrees F", JLabel.CENTER);


    /** initialize farenheit jtextfield for user input
     * and align it center
     */
    farenheit = new JTextField("Input");


    /** add my labels to my grid
     */

    jfrm.add(name, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jfrm.add(enter, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jfrm.add(farenheit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jfrm.add(degreesFarenheit, BorderLayout.EAST);
    jfrm.add(answerCelsius, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    /** attach the action listener to farenheit
     */
    farenheit.addActionListener(this);

    /** makes the frame visible
     */
    jfrm.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    /**
     * try and catch statement error on improper input
     * math for farenheit to celsius conversion
     * formatted string to round to hundreth place
     */
    try {

        double userInput = Double.parseDouble(farenheit.getText());
        double celsius = (userInput - 32) * 5 / 9;
        String roundedCelsius = String.format("%,.2f ", celsius);
        answerCelsius.setText("= "+roundedCelsius+" degrees C");



    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        answerCelsius.setText("Invalid Input");


    }
}


public static void main (String [] args){

    /**
     * run program
     */
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JTemperature();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: As per the documentation and [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) you only have five positions available to you.  You should avoid using `setPreferredSize` as this will reek havoc with your UI in unpleasant ways.  The best solution you have available to you is to use another container with a different layout to achieve what you want

Comment: I built it using Grid layout, and that worked with blank labels, but my teacher has unfortunately given me the restraint of using BorderLayout. I'm not really sure what to turn in. Haha.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a weird requirement

Comment: You can try using multiple JPanels each with a BorderLayout and placing them in the Main panel. Agree with @MadProgrammer that it is a weird requirement for a form.

Comment: *"I am unsure how to properly size my text field .. `farenheit = new JTextField("Input");`"* To suggest a size, set the number of columns / characters the field is intended to display. *"I am not sure how to put the JLabel answerCelsius into the bottom right corner."* If limited to `BorderLayout` I'd use two. A panel with border layout that has the label in the `EAST`, itself in **another** panel with border layout, in the `SOUTH`..

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 1):

> I am told to use BorderLayout for this project. I am unsure how to
>   properly size my text field and I am not sure how to put the JLabel
>   answerCelsius into the bottom right corner.

Here is an approach to position the `answerCelsius` `JLabel` to the bottom right (SouthEast) of the window. This is done using `javax.swing.Box` within the `BorderLayout`. Here is the code I used to accomplish this:

**Option 1**:

*I replaced this line:*

```
jfrm.add(answerCelsius, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

*with this code:*

```
Box hbox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
Component padding = Box.createHorizontalStrut(160);
hbox.add(padding);
hbox.add(answerCelsius);
jfrm.add(hbox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The following screenshots show *before* and *after* the code change:

[image]

[image]

**NOTE**: In the application the padding needs to be adjusted to accomplish this based on the requirement.

**Option 2**:

*Replace this code:*

```
jfrm.add(degreesFarenheit, BorderLayout.EAST);
jfrm.add(answerCelsius, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

*with this code:*

```
Box vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();
Component padding = Box.createVerticalStrut(20);
vbox.add(padding);
vbox.add(degreesFarenheit);
vbox.add(padding);
vbox.add(answerCelsius);
jfrm.add(vbox, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

The result:

[image]